# Use inline Styling to open Select tag up instead of down React

Tags: reactjs, select

I've been looking up this problem all over google and the only result that seems to get the most upvotes on every source is either:
`menuContainerStyle={{top: 'auto', bottom: '100%'}}`
as inline
or something along the lines of:

```
    .Select-menu-outer{
 top: auto;
 bottom: 100%;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
 border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: unset;
 border-bottom-left-radius: unset;
}
```

in CSS. 
But neither of these work for me at all and I'm not sure if I'm missing something or doing it wrong. I just need to be able to have a the Select tag open Up instead of down.

Comment: Can you specify the html piece for this?

Comment: '<select>
     <option/>
</select>'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the potential solution you're referencing (which isn't working for you) comes from here:

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/284

Notice that this site is a GitHub forum for those discussing the `react-select` GitHub project.  But in the comments below your question, you say that your HTML looks like this:

<select><option/></select>

That's not a React component.  That's plain ol' vanilla HTML.  If you're using a plain ol' vanilla HTML <select> menu (even if you're rendering it from within a React component), then I'm pretty confident in saying that you're **never** going to get it to change the direction in which it's opening.

There's a reason for this:  When you use plain ol' vanilla HTML to invoke a <select> menu, that menu is rendered by the browser.  And the browser, in turn, actually figures out how to render a lot of the "basic" form components *from the operating system*.  This means that you can throw all the CSS in the world at it, but in the end, your options to truly customize it are extremely limited.

That's why modern JS frameworks (jQuery, React, whatever...) typically don't use the plain ol' vanilla HTML <select> menu at all.  They've completely discarded it.  (jQuery UI *replaces* your original <select> menu altogether with something more manageable.  Material UI just builds something entirely different that works "like" a <select> menu.)

Which brings us back to the original question and the original proposed solution you found that's not working for you.  It sounds like you either A) have not installed `react-select` or you, B) are not trying to leverage it in this case.

I have no idea if `react-select` will work for you, but if you haven't installed it, you really need to give it a try.  And if you won't install it (or if, for some reason, you can't), then you'll need to look for some other work around because the plain ol' vanilla HTML option isn't going to do what you're trying to do.